# Restoring Firefox tab groups after a power outage

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-tabs, tab-groups

I was web browsing when the power suddenly cut out for a moment, causing my computer to shut down.  After restarting, Firefox Seems to have forgotten about my tab groups and the tabs therein. My profiles, extensions, history, passwords, etc. seem to be okay, but I cannot get Firefox to restore my tab groups and open tabs.

How can I restore my tab groups and tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After panicking for a few minutes, I used Windows' "Restore Previous Version" to restore a previous version of sessionstore.js, which restored my tab groups and tabs.

This sessionstore.js file should be located in `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<your profile name>` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install plug-in Session Manager (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/)

Comment: Will this work after the fact, or do I need to have it installed before the unexpected shutdown?

Comment: Nope. It's a barn door and horse thing. I have it installed on all my Firefoxen thanks to Sync, and it maintains a long session history. Like any back-up tool, it can't help after the fact.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was looking for a method to restore my session after the power outage, not a method of preventing it in the future (though that information is helpful as well).